# Autocomplete component validation primeng

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I want to validade the autocomplete I want to ensure that the value typed in the autocomplete accept only characters.
But the validation isn't work because in this case the autocomplete is saving an object. I need to validate the name of the object.
My validation are validating the object but not the value inserted in the autocompleted. 
I think I can do this with a custom validation but I don't want to use if is possible a custom validation.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
        acto: new FormControl(undefined, [Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*')])
    });
}
```

HTML: The autocomplete store an object with two properties {name: "bla bla bla", id: "123"}

```
<p-autoComplete
    [forceSelection]="true"
    formControlName="acto"
    field="name"
    [suggestions]="actDescription"
    (completeMethod)="searchSpecDescription($event)">
</p-autoComplete>
```

Thank you very much.